# Mediawiki for personal use

Tags: permissions, wiki, web-hosting, mediawiki

I need to setup a mediawiki like wiki for some personal projects. Access control is absolutely essential. I should be able to approve when new users create an account on the system. Therefore, i should be controlling who is able to access the wiki. Also wikitext markup should be supported.

I tried wikkii.com but i dont know how to get the access control thing working there.

**What sites provide this kind of a service?**

Paid services are not a option for me.

---

On searching a lot more i eventually found an answer. [editthis.info](http://editthis.info) is a great website that provides a wiki farm based on mediawiki, with the access control feature!

Comment: People who closed this question: If you close something as off-topic, please leave a comment describing the correct Stackexchange forum for the question or if one does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that setting up Mediawiki itself, as well as an installation of phpBB... and disabling the ability to sign up for a new account through MediaWiki, but installing this [phpBB user integration extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PHPBB/Users_Integration) allowed me to control who could edit the Wiki by controlling who could join the forum.  The forum gave us a place off the Wiki to discuss what was going into it, before it went into it, so to me, it seemed a good mating.

Comment: Which hosting would you recommend?

Comment: One that you are paying for.  I realize you said Paid Services are not an option for you, which means you will have limited control to install ANY of these kinds of things of you try to use a free service.  You are far better off getting a hosting deal on eBay... one of those $10 for 4 years hosting that you see offered.